# How to disable link step in VS2013 project configuration?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, linker, projects-and-solutions

I would like to disable the linker for a particular project configuration of a VS2013 C++ project. How can I do this?

I have tried to remove the output path, remove the `<Link>` parts of the project file, but this only results in error messages ("error : The OutputPath property is not set for project" / "error: The output paths do not match" etc.)

The reason is that this particular configuration does preprocessing to file so no object files are created, which always results in a linker error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [compiler switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8we9bhf4.aspx) **/c** to "compile only". Unfortunately this is only available outside of Visual Studio. So you would need to build the project on the command line using cl.exe.

Comment: This would be what I need, it's a bit crazy that VS even ignores this switch when I specify it in the project settings as an additional commandline option.

Comment: yes a shame ... on a per file basis you can do this by settings the files "item type" to "custom build tool" and specify a commandline to build that one file